# Distributing a .NET Core project under GPL

Tags: licensing, gpl

Although the source code of the most .NET Core components is licensed under a MIT License, the binary files of the .NET Core runtime and other supporting libraries on NuGet are released under [a more restrictive license](https://www.microsoft.com/net/dotnet_library_license.htm).

> iii. Distribution Restrictions. You may not
>
> - alter any copyright, trademark or patent notice in the Distributable Code;
> - use Microsoft’s trademarks in your programs’ names or in a way that suggests your programs come from or are endorsed by Microsoft;
> - include Distributable Code in malicious, deceptive or unlawful programs; or
> - **modify or distribute the source code of any Distributable Code so that any part of it becomes subject to an Excluded License. An Excluded License is one that requires, as a condition of use, modification or distribution, that**
>
>   - **the code be disclosed or distributed in source code form; or**
>   - **others have the right to modify it.**

According to the above text from that license, it seems that GPL is an `Excluded License`.

So I can't distribute a .NET Core project under GPL, or I've misunderstood something?

Comment: Typically one doesn't distribute runtimes. You let your users grab it from official sources themselves.

Comment: @RubberDuck But do the runtimes subject to GPL? I've read about `System Library` definition in GPL, but still not sure if .NET Core runtimes are `System Libraries`.

Comment: Your project is not subject to the licensing restrictions of the runtime. They are two separate things.

Comment: @RubberDuck You're right. I read the definition of `System Library` again. The .NET Core runtime is a `System Library` since its packaged along with the compiler, so it is not restricted by the GPL I used in my project.

Comment: @RubberDuck And what about the libraries released on NuGet? e.g. `System.Collections.Specialized`. It is not distributed with the .NET Core SDK and require DLL files to work. I think it subjects to GPL.

Comment: You cannot subject those libraries to the GPL.

Comment: @RubberDuck I've understood. Thank you for your comments. Would you like to post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have understood things correctly: the GPL and copyleft licenses are explicitly targeted here without naming them. So you cannot redistribute things in a way that would make Microsoft software subject to a copyleft.

Since these are system libraries, you would likely not redistribute them and should not.

But if you are saying that this license is for pre-built binaries and that the sources are MIT-licensed, then use the sources, do not reuse the binaries and be happy. The MIT is considered as compatible with the A/L/GPL licenses. And you could released binaries built from these sources combined with your copyleft-licensed code.